# ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape when plotting a bar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I tried to make a bar plot.

**purchase_value**

|  | Buy_Coffee | Buy_ColdDrinks | Buy_Juices | Buy_Pastries | Buy_Sandwiches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

```
plt.bar(purchase_value.index,
    purchase_value.value_counts(), 
    width=0.5, 
    bottom=None, 
    align='center', 
    color=['lightsteelblue', 
           'cornflowerblue', 
           'royalblue', 
           'midnightblue', 
           'darkblue'])
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

**But it turned out**

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: Are you sure `purchase_value.value_counts()` is what you want? That will give you a count of each of the unique rows which in this case isn't going to match the length of the index. Can you clarify in the question what values you want in the bar plot?

Comment: I want to know the sum of each item in a column. Like the first column "buy coffee" is 5.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [**`pandas.DataFrame.value_counts`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html), you are computing the count for each unique combination of rows values.
So, by applying this to data you provided, you get:

```
Buy_Coffee  Buy_ColdDrinks  Buy_Juices  Buy_Pastries  Buy_Sandwiches
1           0               0           0             0                 3
                                                      1                 2
0           1               0           1             0                 1
```

The number of combinations could be not equal to the number of lines (`purchase_value.index`) in your data.
If I understand correctly what you want to plot, you should use:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

purchase_value = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

purchase_value.plot(kind = 'bar',
                    ax = ax,
                    stacked = True, 
                    width=0.5, 
                    bottom=0, 
                    align='center', 
                    color=['lightsteelblue', 
                           'cornflowerblue', 
                           'royalblue', 
                           'midnightblue', 
                           'darkblue'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you would to draw the sum of each item for each column, you should use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

purchase_value.sum(axis = 0).plot(kind = 'bar',
                                  ax = ax,
                                  stacked = True, 
                                  width=0.5, 
                                  bottom=0, 
                                  align='center', 
                                  color=['lightsteelblue', 
                                         'cornflowerblue', 
                                         'royalblue', 
                                         'midnightblue', 
                                         'darkblue'])

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't explain clearly. The second plot is what I want! I'm so appreciate with that!